# JAXB unmarshal xml file problems

Tags: java, jaxb

i have problem to unmarshalling JAXB objects

I need to parse some xml files and i have xsd file,
So i auto generate xsd to JAXB Classes use eclipse.

How to get Class from this method???

```
protected List<JAXBElement<?>> getOBJECT();
```

Generated JAXB Class Like this

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementsRef(name = "ClazzA" type=JAXBElemnt.class, requered = false),
    @XmlElementsRef(name = "ClazzB" type=JAXBElemnt.class, requered = false),
    @XmlElementsRef(name = "ClazzC" type=JAXBElemnt.class, requered = false),
    @XmlElementsRef(name = "ClazzD" type=JAXBElemnt.class, requered = false),
    ....
})
```

NOTE : The xml files are unorganized, maybe some elements are not using in some xml

I searched some unmarshall references,

But many cases JAXB classes are organized, so i cant use them...